# NSWindow with custom shadow

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow

I want to draw a custom shadow on an NSWindow-Object.

Is there a way to do this by passing an own NSShadow-Object to NSWindow? Or a (private) method, where I can put my own drawing code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Don't. You shouldn't alter the look of the window. Changing the look of UI is only allowed for Apple. Normal apps should use  the standard one.

That said, there's a way, if you really insist on doing that. You can't just attach an `NSShadow`, unfortunately. Also, as far as I understand, there's no private method which draw the shadow. That's done by the Window Server, not by the app.

But you can ask the window server not to add the shadow. Have you noticed that in the Interface Builder, there's an option suppressing the shadow of a given window? That corresponds to the property [`hasShadow`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/hasShadow) of an `NSWindow`.

After suppressing the shadow, you just need to draw everything by yourself. A nice sample code that does the custom window drawing is available at [ADC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html), so have a look at it.

Comment: Had a look at the example cited. While it's a good example for drawing a transparent borderless window, it doesn't say very much for manually drawing the window's shadow -- it just uses the default shadow based on the contents of the transparent borderless window (in this case a circle/pentagon image). A related question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948228/make-borderless-window-with-darker-larger-shadow

Comment: @Yuji, I noticed that the default NSWindow shadow has two different shadows when it is on focus and when not. Basically there is more shadow when on focus. How can get that behaviour using the ADC?